# WebSQL selecting child + parent

Tags: sql, web-sql

I'm trying to export a list of categories with it's childs.
the designer of the DB made it so that a parent category can have the same ID of a child

so the query should return a list of:

- Parent items
- Child items with the parent name

I'm trying to do this in 1 Query, So I did the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, pc.name as parentName 
FROM Category as c 
INNER JOIN Category as pc on c.parent_id = pc.id 
WHERE c.building_id = 1 
AND (
  c.parent_id = -1 
  OR (
    c.usingtemplate = 'true'
    AND 
    pc.parent_id = -1
  )
);
```

but the parents aren't in the list

I have a sql fiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/75dd9/83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a **LEFT JOIN** did the trick

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, pc.name as parentName 
FROM Category as c 
LEFT JOIN Category as pc on c.parent_id = pc.id 
WHERE c.building_id = 1 
AND (
  c.parent_id = -1 
  OR (
    c.usingtemplate = 'true'
    AND 
    pc.parent_id = -1
  )
);
```